# How to generate animated GIF of a Manipulate? 8.0.1

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Exporting to animated gif seems to have changed in Mathematica 8.0.1?

I normally make animated GIFs of a manipulate by simply writing:

```
v=Manipulate[....]

then Export["foo.gif",v];
```

But now it does not work. I just get one static image.

Here is an example:

```
v=Manipulate[
Text[t],
{{t,4,"start"},0,10,1,ControlType->Trigger,AnimationRate->1,AnimationRepetitions->10}
]
```

Now `Export["foo.gif",v]` just generate static image, as nothing was running.

But `Export["foo.avi",v]` works, and it does generate a running avi movie.

Also, there used to be animated GIF options I used before, but now there are not supported:

```
Export["foo.gif",v,ConversionOptions->{"AnimationDisplayTime"->0.5,"Loop"->True},ImageSize->{500,500}]

Export::convoptobs: ConversionOptions is obsolete.
```

When I go to help, I do not see options for GIF there. How does one control animation delay and such?

I thought someone here might have an idea.

thanks
--Nasser

Comment: I don't use version 8, but I am curious to know what you get if you use:  `Export["foo.gif", {v}]`

Comment: Same effect when I used {v}, no animated gif generated.

Comment: A shame it wasn't that simple.  I am afraid I cannot be of help.

Comment: @Nasser What *Mathematica* version were you using that worked in the mentioned way? I tried `v=Manipulate[Text[t],{{t,4,"start"},0,10,1,ControlType->Trigger,AnimationRate->1,AnimationRepetitions->10}];Export["C:/foo.gif",v]` in the version 7.0.1 and it does generate a static image.

Comment: Hello; I do not remember which version. But I do remember that I used to be able to export to animated gif a variable which I had set equal to the Maniupulate command. I could be may be wrong, but it does work with SWF and AVI?

As for the options (for the Export to gif part) I do know for sure these used to work before, and now they no longer work.

Either way, the question still, how would one export a Manipulate to animated gif file? Using Animate[] as was suggested instead of Manipulate did not work well for my case (UI changed a little when I did that).

Thanks
--Nasser

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can export a `Table` to an animated GIF.

```
v = Table[Panel[Text[t]], {t, 0, 10, 1}];
Export["anim.gif", v, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.5]
```

If you absolutely want the animation to look like a `Manipulate`, you could do something like so.

```
v = Table[Manipulate[Text[t], 
    {{t, Mod[k, 10], "start"}, 0, 10, 1, ControlType -> Trigger}],
  {k, 4, 14}];
Export["Manip.gif", v, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.5]
```

Comment: Thank you Mark! That did it. I wanted to vote your answer up, but it forum won't let me. I used your trick to finally animate a small Manipulate I did for school HW. If you like to see the animation, here it is 

http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_demos/pendulum_flywheel/index.htm

I used latex to load it, scaled it down a little. Thanks again ! I like this forum much more than the other Math group, as there is no long delay here and one can finally talk Mathematica at well.

--Nasser

Comment: @Nasser - Glad to help!  And I'm glad you like this forum.  It's certainly different from mathgroup.  I'm sure they both have their strengts, but I definitely like the turn around here.  Concerning the upvote, you need to earn a bit of reputation before you can do so.  I don't think it's too much.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `v = Animate[
  Text[t], {{t, 4, "start"}, 0, 10, 1, ControlType -> Trigger, 
   AnimationRate -> 1, AnimationRepetitions -> 10}]`